# My .htaccess loads but my rewrite rule doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Current code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^url-testing/index\.php\?var\=indexs$ /url-testing/indexs.php [L]
```

Original URL: `localhost/url-testing/indexs`

Rewritten URL: `localhost/url-testing/index.php?var=indexs`

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn your rule around:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /
RewriteRule   ^url-testing/indexs$   url-testing/index.php?var=indexs [R,L,NC]
```

Alternatively for a more global rule:

```
RewriteRule   ^url-testing/(*.?)$    url-testing/index.php?var=$1 [R,L,NC]
```

You also need to check options for this virtual host, make sure in options that this is set:

```
AllowOverride All
```